# Trouble finding a document in my FTP using Chrome/Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

[My FTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/243pX.png)

Currently looking through my directory of my site build. I'm hoping to edit a LINK , but having trouble finding where the actual pages to edit are.

I can find the link that needs editing (using Chrome/Inspect element) but unable to find the actual document in my FTP. Is there a tab or location that will show me the actual name?

The 'SOURCES' Tab DOES show me file names but that file does not exist in my actual directory.
[SOURCES TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R74wC.png)

[Chrome/ Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7qHq.png)

Any place I'm not looking?

Thank You!

Comment: Can you share a little more information on what you are actually looking for? FTP will always show you the server side files that may or may not reflect what is getting downloaded on the client-side in the browser. That's how web applications are built.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for the HREF link (It's highlighted on the CHROME/INSPECT ELEMENT screenshot in the original message). I just want to change that URL but not sure where that actual line of code lives.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find any code/link is to download all files in local system and use any IDE to perform "FIND ALL FILES". Following is the way how I tackle this:

- Once you installed Notepad++ software, open the Notepad++.
- Press Ctrl+F to open the Find and replace tool.
- Open Find in files tab. Fill in the Find what: field and select the directory for the search (folder with your site files, template package, theme folder, etc.)

[image]

Click on Find all button.

You will see the files and lines with the text you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great tip! I'll give it a try and see if I can track it down that way!- Thanks again!